# Ignore case with boost::regexp

Tags: c++, case-insensitive, boost-regex

Strangely enough, google refuses to answer such simple question:
How do I make boost::regexp case-insensitive?

This is what I have:

```
static const boost::regex bad_words("(?:^|.* )(f(?:uc|a)k(?:i[ng]{1,2})?|bitch(?:es|iz)?)(?:$| .*)");   //reduced to the english ones
```

Of course, I want to filter uppercase bad words as well. This is how I match them:

```
//std::string ms; - chat messsage
//boost::match_results<std::string::const_iterator> results;  - prewious regexp results
else if(boost::regex_match(ms, results2, bad_words)) {   //
        std::stringstream msg;
        msg<<"Avoid bad words! Word '"<<results2[1]<<"' is banned!";
        this->whisper(results[1], msg.str());   //name, message
}
```

So, is there another function for insensitive regexp? Or another regexp object? Or the modifier `i` is available?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the `boost::regex::icase` option:

```
static const boost::regex bad_words("...your regex...", boost::regex::icase);
```